# how to add php5.6 mbstring extension in centos 6.8

Tags: php, apache

My terminal shows php version as

```
[root@localhost modules]# php -v
PHP 5.6.25 (cli) (built: Oct 21 2016 17:57:17) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

and when I check for mbstring extension for php with `php -m` command I get

but when i check with yum list installed php* i get this

```
php-mbstring.x86_64 5.6.30-1.el6.remi @remi-php56
```

when I check with phpinfo() I get result as

1) i get related result in Additional ini file parsed section as

I try with new installation of php56w-mbstring also then also same problem.

Comment: `install php5-mbstring`

Comment: what is the output of "which php", and "rpm -qf $(which php)"  ?

Comment: If above report "/usr/bin/php" and "php-cli-5.6.30-1.el6.remi", as you have "php-mbstring.x86_64 5.6.30-1.el6.remi " installed, it should work, so I suspect an manually (from source)  installed somewhere else (probably in /usr/local)

Comment: i have already installed this but not working with php cli 5.6

Comment: what is the output of "which php", and "rpm -qf $(which php)" ? – Remi Collet 34 mins ago  i get this     
 
/opt/rh/rh-php56/root/usr/bin/php              and for      second          rh-php56-php-cli-5.6.25-1.el6.x86_64

Comment: I got this problem when i am trying to install yii2 on centos 6.8 m php cli 5.6 and mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.54, apache.

Comment: As you use rh-php56-php-cli, you need rh-php56-php-mbstring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Diagnostic**

1/ find which **php command** is used:

```
which php
```

2/ find which **package** provides this command

```
rpm --query --file $(which php)
```

If this fails, this probably means you are using a manually installed PHP version, built from sources, usually in /usr/local.

**Installation**

As, in your case php is provided by **rh-php56-php-cli**, you need to install needed extensions, from the same repository (centos-sclo) and in the **same namespace** (rh-php56):

```
yum install rh-php56-php-mbstring
```

Comment: No package rh-php56-php-mbstring available.

Answer (score 0):

```
Its small mistake here... 
In my setup there are two version for php 
1)php with apahce and
2)php cli 
[root@localhost modules]# which php
/opt/rh/rh-php56/root/usr/bin/php

[root@localhost modules]# find / -name php.ini
/opt/rh/rh-php56/register.content/etc/opt/rh/rh-php56/php.ini

/etc/opt/rh/rh-php56/php.ini
/etc/php.ini

here i select /etc/opt/rh/rh-php56/php.ini and after this check for mbstring in terminal by i fine mbstring.so file
as 

[root@localhost modules]# find / -name mbstring.so
/usr/lib64/php/modules/mbstring.so
/usr/lib64/php-zts/modules/mbstring.so

with gedit /etc/opt/rh/rh-php56/php.ini i added that extension and related path with it as
extension=/usr/lib64/php/modules/mbstring.so

after that check with 
php -m 
now i get mbstring with this command.
```

Comment: For installation of yii its necessary that we have to go with php cli version mainly its main point for the yii2 installation.

Comment: NO, very bad solution, as I said in previous comment, install "rh-php56-php-mbstring"